# fpdf table rows breaks from second page

Tags: pdf, fpdf

I'm trying to output a data table extracted from database using FPDF.

My problem is that the first page of output is coming as it is expected, but after the table ends in first page and it goes to second page then rows of table are coming in one row per page.

I tried searching whole internet thing but i couldn't find out the suitable answer with reference to my below code. Below is my fpdf file code.

```
<?php

require('fpdf.php');
include("pdoconnect.php");

class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{
$this->Image('picture.png',10,6,30);
$this->SetFont('Arial','B',15);
// Move to the right
$this->Cell(80);
// Title
$this->SetTextColor( 255, 119, 0 );
$this->Cell(30,10,'Report',0,0,'C');
 // Line break
$this->Line(10, 22, 210-10, 22);
$this->Ln(20);
}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{   
$this->Line(10, 280, 210-10, 280);
$this->SetY(-15);
$this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
// Page number
$this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
  }
}

$result='SELECT * FROM report WHERE time BETWEEN "'.$_POST["fromdate"].'" AND "'.$_POST["todate"].'"';
$link=$db->prepare($result);
$link->execute();
$resultset=$link->fetchAll();
$count=$link->rowCount();

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();
$pdf->SetTitle("Report"); 
$pdf->AddPage();

$row_height = 10;
$y_axis=30;


$pdf->SetY($y_axis);
$pdf->SetX(25);
$pdf->Cell(30, 10,"", 0, 0, 1);
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;



$pdf->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(102, 68, 34 );
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 10);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis);
$pdf->SetX(11);
$pdf->Cell(34,10,'Order ID',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(35,10,'Name',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(30,10,'TID',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,10,'Quantity',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,10,'Date',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(20,10,'Time',1,0,'C');
$pdf->Cell(30,10,'Bill Amount',1,0,'C');
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
$total=0;
foreach($resultset as $row)
{
    $len=strlen($row['name']);
    if($len>21)
{
     $name=substr($row['name'],0,19)."..";
}
 else
{
    $name = $row['name'];
 }



$oid    = $row['order_id'];

$tid    = $row['t_id'];
$qty    = $row['quantity'];
$date   = $row['date'];
$time   = $row['time'];
$amt    = $row['bill_amount'];

$total=$total+$amt;

$pdf->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', '', 9);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis);
$pdf->SetX(11);
$pdf->Cell(34, 10, $oid, 1, 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(35, 10, $name, 1, 0, 'L');
$pdf->Cell(30, 10, $tid, 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, $qty, 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, $date, 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(20, 10, $time, 1, 0, 'C');
$pdf->Cell(30, 10, $amt, 1, 0, 'R');

$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
$pdf->SetY(10);
$pdf->SetX(170);




}

$totalre=$total-$r_amt;
$pdf->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 11);
$pdf->SetY($y_axis);
$pdf->SetX(137);
$pdf->Cell(42, 10,'Total', 0, 0, 'C');
$pdf->SetTextColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->Cell(25, 10, $totalre , 0, 0, 'C');
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(false,20);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

I want the second page displayed as first page without splitting the table rows. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the yAxis being greater than the height of the page, you will need to manually add pages and reset the yAxis using something similar to:

```
if ($y_axis + $row_height >= $pdf->GetPageHeight() - 20)
{
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $y_axis = 30;
}
```

after incrementing the yAxis (the -20 is to allow space for the footer)

The code should be included as below:

```
$y_axis = $y_axis + $row_height;

if ($y_axis + $row_height >= $pdf->GetPageHeight() - 20)
{
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $y_axis = 30;
}

$pdf->SetY(10);
$pdf->SetX(170);
```

inside your foreach loop

Comment: Its showing `Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDF::GetPageHeight()` .Where I have to include your code in above my code?

Comment: Interesting - worked fine for me using the latest version of FPDF - try changing $pdf->GetPageHeight() to $pdf->h

Comment: After changing it to `$pdf->h` ,error is not coming but my problem is not solved. Still no change in my output. :(

Comment: I included ur code at the end of my code just before `$pdf->Output();` . Is that correct?

Comment: Nope - it needs to be included when you increment the yAxis in your loop.

Comment: Yea.. Worked.. Thanks a lot bro... I just did the same as u updated.